# PyPi: twine missing METADATA, but it exists in .whl file

Tags: python, pypi, twine

I was trying to upload an update to my package on PyPi but I noticed they have changed it so you have to use a `pyproject.toml` file.
So I did follow steps on [PyPi](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/)

1. Created `pyproject.toml`
2. Ran `py -m build` with no errors or warnings
3. Ran `twine check dist/*` and both files passed
4. Ran `twine upload dist/*` to upload, but got this error after the first file was uploaded:

```
Wheel '***_Ashenguard-3.2.0-py3-none-any.whl' does not contain the required METADATA file: ***_ashenguard-3.2.0.dist-info/METADATA
```

(*** = My package)

Then I opened the `.whl` file (Changed its suffix to zip and opened it) and checked the files inside and I saw the METADATA file in the path specified...

I tried searching but the only similar question I found was solved by adding the `pyproject.toml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem today. Maybe the TestPyPI switched to case-sensitive package name comparison. I changed my package name from "FOO" to "foo" and it seems to be successfully uploaded to TestPyPI.

Comment: Thank you, You are a life saver as whole my team was stopped waiting for the package... It was my case too...

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/